# Does ruby have nor?

Tags: ruby

Ruby has the conditional `unless`.

Does it have `nor`?

E.g.

```
unless 1 == 2 nor 1 == 3
  "nothing equal"
else
  "something's equal"
end
```

Comment: Is there a reason you can't do `if 1 == 2 or 1 == 3`?

Comment: No, but in some rare occasions, linguistically it makes more sense to use the negation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ruby doesn't have a built-in nor, but you could extend the built-in booleans like so:

```
class TrueClass
  def nor(other)
    false
  end
end

class FalseClass
  def nor(other)
    !other
  end
end
```

and then write

```
unless (1 == 2).nor(1 == 3)
  "nothing equal"
else
  "something's equal"
end
```

Comment: This doesn't really work that well. `nil` is also falsey, `'pancakes'` is truthy, ... and your `nor` only works true booleans. Your `nor` also won't short circuit the way a `||` and `&&` do.

Answer (score 1):

Nope... but you can simulate it like this:

```
unless 1 != 2 && 1 != 3
  "nothing equal"
else
  "something's equal"
end
```